# Power supply upgrade for gaming computer

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, power-supply

I'm thinking of adding a second Sapphire R9 390 to my computer to run in 2x crossfire.

Here are the parts I'm using:

- CPU: Intel i5-6600k
- MB: Asus Z170-A ATX LGA1151
- RAM: Kingston HyperX Fury Black 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4-2133
- Storage: Samsung 850 EVO-Series 250GB SSD and Seagate Barracuda 2TB
  3.5" 7200RPM
- Case: Corsair 200R ATX Mid Tower
- **GPU:   Sapphire Radeon R9 390 8GB Nitro**
- **PSU: EVGA SuperNOVA GS 650W 80+ Gold**

The power requirements of such an upgrade would technically be covered by my current PSU, but only by a very small margin.
Also, my PSU only provides enough cables for a single GPU.

The theoretical power draw is around 750W so I'm looking for something in the waters of 800-900W
Fully modular and silent operation on idle are both big pluses.

High reliability is a must!

**What would be a good model to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the best choice for paid money I would recommend:

**[EVGA SuperNOVA 850 P2](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=220-P2-0850-X1)** - [$160 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817438056&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-VigLink2-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3821802&SID=ink39bbf9v0035wt00053)

---

**Description:**

This PSU has **Platinum certificate** and it was made on Super Flower platform so it guarantees high quality of components. It is **passive** until load around **340W**. It has avarage efficiency on low loads around **84.2 %** and on normal loads avarage efficiency is **92.5%**. EVGA also comes with **10 years warranty** what is really good offer.

---

**Most important features:**

- 80 Plus Platinum certified
- semi-passive - quiet until ~340W load
- really good efficiency results on low and normal loads
- 10 years warranty
- fully modular

---

**Final conclusion:**

It is really good PSU made on components from SuperFlower. If you are looking for best efficiency for spend dollar you should think about this PSU. It will work good with your setup and stay quiet when PC is idle or it is under small load. If it's not enough for you should think about Titanium EVGA PSU which I described in my [other answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2605/1366).

Comment: Can you explain *why*? This looks very similar to your other answer. Why is this one the best choice for your money vs. the other's best performance?

Comment: @Andy Because the other is very similar but it has better (top-end) efficiency I would normally put this two PSU's in one answer and try to compare them as one being best possible 850W PSU and other really reliable and also cheaper choice. But after this [answer](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/482/1366) I have to split products in two anserws and it's hard to compare them in two different answers. Generally I think both PSU's are great choices cheaper one is really good but if price is no listed in question I will also provide answer with best PSU in my opinion (not economical).

Comment: I understand why you have two answers (I wrote the linked meta answer). I'm just asking for a bit of explanation, because on this question I see "I recommend this." and 4 bullet points. There should be a bit of prose to help users see why this model is good for your wallet while the other is good for performance. Basically, more than just a list. A list is a good start, but the explanation is very helpful too. It helps in the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the best performance not looking at price of the PSU I would recommend:

**[EVGA SuperNOVA 850 T2](http://www.evga.com/products/Product.aspx?pn=220-T2-0850-X1)** - [$220 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817438064&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-VigLink2-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3821802&SID=ink3945mb40035wt00053)

---

**Description:**

If there is no price limit the best avaliable PSU's have **Titanium certificate** like SuperNova T2. It was made on Super Flower platform so it guarantees high quality of components. It is **passive** until load around **500W**. It has avarage efficiency on low loads around **88.7 %** and on normal loads avarage efficiency is **94%**. EVGA also comes with **10 years warranty** what is really good offer.

---

**Most important features:**

- 80 Plus Titanium certified
- semi-passive - quiet until ~500W load
- top end efficiency
- 10 years warranty
- fully modular

---

**Final conclusion:**

It is top end PSU made on components from SuperFlower with higest performance among 850W PSU's. If you are looking for hardware and not looking at price you should think about buying this product. If you want to buy PSU which will work also good with your setup and will be cheaper (but not so quiet and with worse efficiency) I would recommend my [other answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2606/1366).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to recommend the [Corsair HXi HX850i CP-9020073-NA 850W](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/hxi-series-hx850i-high-performance-atx-power-supply-850-watt-80-plus-platinum-certified-psu). This is a fully modular 850 Watt power supply that is 80 PLUS Platinum certified. It has a built in fan, but it doesn't even turn on until the load reaches around 350 Watts.

This unit comes with a handful of unique features, like the fan test button. With this, you can test the operation of the fan even before installing the PSU into your case. The unit also has a mini USB port that you can either plug directly into the motherboard (included cable) or into a USB port on the back of the computer. With this, you can monitor performance and adjustment of fan speed and multi-rail/single rail mode. I do not remember seeing a driver disk in the box, but it is easily downloadable by following this [link](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/support/downloads), selecting "Corsair Link", and selecting the most recent file at the top.

Corsair lists the 850 Watt unit at $199.99 (USD) not on sale, but if you shop around, you can find a lower price.

Corsair also has a 1000 and 1200 Watt version of the same PSU, so if you want a bit more breathing room, you have options.